# Label encoding in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with data set which have numerical and categorical values. I find solution with numerical values, so next step is to make label encoding with categorical values. In order to do that I wrote these lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset_categorical = dataset.select_dtypes(include = ['object'])
new_column = dataset_categorical.astype('category')
```

After execution of last line of code in Jupyter I can't see an error, but values are not converted into encoded values.
Also this line work for example when I try with only one column but don't work with whole data frame.

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "ecncoded values"? Are you looking for `pandas.factorize`? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = {
    'Name':['George','Andrea','micheal','maggie','Ravi',
               'Xien','Jalpa'],
   'Is_Male':[1,0,1,0,1,1,0]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['Name','Is_Male'])
```

#### Typecast to Categorical column in pandas

```
df1['Is_Male'] = df1.Is_Male.astype('category')
```